# Software SPI 3-wire read register

Tags: spi, gpio, register

I currently try to read a register from an acceleration sensor (ADXL345). i try to simulate the SPI procedure with software. I wrote a `readRegister` function:

```
uint8_t readRegister(uint8_t reg) {
    uint8_t i, k;
    uint8_t res = 0; 
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<CS);
    delay_ms(2); 

    // write register address
    GPIOD->DDR |= (1<<SDIO);            // SDIO as output
    for(i=0; i<8; i++) {       
            GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK);      
            if(reg & (1<<7)) {            
                    GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SDIO);    
            } else {                        
                    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SDIO); 
            }
            delay_ms(1);                   
            GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK);       
            delay_ms(1);                   
            reg <<= 1;                      
    }

    // read result
    GPIOD->DDR &= ~(1<<SDIO);           // set SDIO as input
    for(k=0; k<8; k++) {        // loop over data bits
            res <<= 1;                      
            GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK);       
            delay_ms(1);        
            GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK);   
            if(GPIOD->IDR & (1<<SDIO)) {  
                    res |= 1;                 
            }                        
            delay_ms(1); 
    }

    GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<CS);             
    return res; 
}
```

The function returns `227` (so `11100011`) instead of `119` (`01110111`) even though i wrote `119` to it with this code:

```
void enableADXL345(){
    uint8_t write;
    uint8_t addr;
    uint8_t data;
    uint8_t result;
    uint16_t write_command;
    uint8_t read_command;

    addr = 0x31;
    data = 0x04;
    write_command = (write | addr) << 8 | data; //set SPI 3-wire
    writeCommand(write_command);

    addr = 0x27;
    data = 0x77;
    write_command = (write | addr) << 8 | data; //write something
    writeCommand(write_command);

    read_command = (0b10000000 | addr);
    result = readRegister(read_command); //read something
}
```

This is my `write` function:

```
void writeCommand(uint16_t cmd){
    uint16_t i;

    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<CS);
    delay_ms(2);
    GPIOD->DDR |= (1<<SDIO);  //SDIO as output
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){ //start to transfer the register we want to read
        GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK);
        if(cmd & (1<<7)){
            GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SDIO);
        } else {
            GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SDIO);
        }
        GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK);
        delay_ms(1);
        cmd <<= 1;
    }
    GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<CS);
}
```

This is the SPI-read/write as described in the datasheet:
[image]

Comment: You need to continue toggling the SCLK signal when you are doing the read. The accelerometer will not push data out if there is no clock. Add your clock the same way you have it in the loop above (where you are pushing out the address).

Comment: In addition to Catsunsmi's point about your lack of a clock during the read phase, why are you reading from your port's DDR register? Isn't that for setting input/output direction?

Answer (score 1):

- Like you've been told in the comments, you need to drive the clock line when you're reading from the sensor.
- You also need to read data from `GPIOD->IDR` instead of `GPIOD->DDR`.
- This sensor uses SPI mode 3 and you arent implementing the protocol correctly. The SCLK line should be idle HIGH when you're done writing, like this:

  ```
  GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<CS);
  delay_ms(2);
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //start to transfer the register we want to read
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK);   // setup data
    if(reg & 128){
        GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SDIO);
    } else {
      GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SDIO);
    }
    GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK);  // now capture data
    delay_ms(1);
    reg <<= 1;
  }
  ```
- Finally, you're getting 0x00 because you're checking the state of the DDR bit. Since the bit is 0, because *you* cleared it right before the while loop, this weird statement `resData = (0<<0);` is always executed and so the function returns 0. You should read from the sensor this way:

  ```
  resData = 0;
  GPIOD->DDR &= ~(1<<SDIO); //set SDIO as Input
  while(k > 0){ //read 8 bit
      delay_ms(1);
      GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK);  // allow the sensor to setup data
      delay_ms(1);
      GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK);  // now capture data
      resData <<= 1;
      resData |= GPIOD->IDR & (1 << SDIO) ? 1 : 0;
      k--;
  }
  return resData;
  ```
- You arent writing properly to the module and you also have a casting issue in your main code. Look at the changes I've made:

  ```
  void writeCommand(uint16_t cmd){
    uint8_t i; 
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<CS); 
    delay_ms(2); 
    GPIOD->DDR |= (1<<SDIO); //SDIO as output 
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){ //start to transfer the register we want to read 
      GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SCLK); 
      if(cmd & (1<<15)){ 
        GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SDIO); 
      } else { 
        GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1<<SDIO); 
      }
      delay_ms(1);
      GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<SCLK); 
      delay_ms(1); 
      cmd <<= 1; 
    } 

    GPIOD->ODR |= (1<<CS); 
  }
  ```

You should cast this way:

```
    write = 0;  // no real need for ORing though
    write_command = ((write | (uint16_t)addr) << 8) | data;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38508/discussion-between-tisteandii-and-binarybigint).

Comment: @binaryBigInt I'm referring to the SDO pin not SDIO. The datasheet says to pull it up to Vcc for proper operation. Also have you tried just reading DEVID alone like i said?

Comment: If i read DEVID without writing something i get the value `72`. I use this board: http://www.ebay.com/itm/191674294902 and `SDO` is my `SDIO` pin, `SDA` is then `SDO`, isn't it? If that's true, i think i don't have the possiblity to pull this pin to Vcc because i already use Vcc to provide power for the chip.

Comment: @binaryBigInt I recommend you read the datasheet of this IC. The SDO pin is NOT the SDIO pin. The SDIO pin is the same as the SDA pin. You have been using the wrong pin for SDIO all this time. Pull the SDO pin to GND thru a 10k resistor. Also the default SPI mode is 4-wire. To use 3-wire, you must first set bit 6 of register 0x31 i.e. write 0x40 to addr 0x31. Again, read the datasheet.

Comment: Maybe it is not working because i need to push 17bits (R/W, MB, 7 Address bits and 8 data bits) to the IC?

Comment: @binaryBigInt No, there are SIX address bits, A5 - A0. Have you corrected the mistakes yet?

Comment: I connected my `SDIO` pin to `SDA` and i also write `0x40` to register `0x31`. I don't think the missing pull down resistor is the mistake because according to the datasheet it is only `recommended`. I now get`8` as value if i read the `DEVID` register

Comment: i wrote smth in chat